# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing resource 'empty.pptx'

Tags: exception, apache-poi, powerpoint

```
package ppt_gen;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;

public class CreatePresentation {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

      //creating a new empty slide show
      XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();         

      //creating an FileOutputStream object
      File file =new File("example1.pptx");
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

      //saving the changes to a file
      ppt.write(out);
      System.out.println("Presentation created successfully");
      out.close();
   }
}
```

What is the cause behind this exception??
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing resource 'empty.pptx'
    at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow.empty(XMLSlideShow.java:98)
    at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow.(XMLSlideShow.java:73)
    at ppt_gen.CreatePresentation.main(CreatePresentation.java:12)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: It looks like you've somehow corrupted your Apache POI jars. How are you doing your build? How are you adding the POI jars to the classpath?

Comment: i have added the jars in library.........//

Comment: How? Please show steps taken. It's very important as you seem to be corrupting the jars in the process!